# TYPO3 dmmjobscontrol can't translate in multi languages

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I use TYPO3 version 4.7.7 and I use dmm_jobsconrols extension version 2.5.2 when I view jobs in detail and I switch language It can't translate and show message:

> "This job does not exist or is not available anymore."

Here my typoScript:

```
40 = TEXT
40.data = GP:tx_dmmjobcontrol_pi1|job_uid
40.wrap = &tx_dmmjobcontrol_pi1[job_uid]=|
40.required = 1
```

Comment: Do you mean that in the alternate language also it is showing english?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether there is a translation for the locallang value "job_not_found" (This job does not exist or is not available anymore.) in the locallang file corresponding to the language that you have switched to. If there's no translation or no locallang file for that language, you need to create it.

Also you can give translation using typoscript in the following way:

```
plugin.dmmjobcontrol._LOCAL_LANG.de.job_not_found = Dieser Job existiert nicht oder ist nicht mehr verfügbar.
```

General syntax:

```
plugin.[PluginName]._LOCAL_LANG.[language:default|de|fr|...] {
 varName = varWert
}
```

Reference link: http://wiki.typo3.org/TypoScript_language_additions,_override